# I can see the "PipelineTracingService" as Type name in the plugin trace log having the Operation Type = "Unknown"

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have observed a different `Type` and `Message` in Plugin trace logs i.e. "**PipelineTracingService**". 
I have found that there are too many logs appearing and even having no `Created On` and `Execution On` date appearing.

Could anyone give an understanding about the "**PipelineTracingService**" and why is it appearing?

Answer (score 1):

This appears when you are doing Plugin profiling using Plugin Profiler. This happens from repro steps of profiled plugin step - irrespective of whether you are creating record in Plugin profiles (Persist to Entity) or throwing UI error popup to download profile (Exception).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the response.

Comment: but what should be the resolution?

Comment: @MunavvarHusein why is it bothering you? what resolution you want? Edit the question, thanks

Comment: We don't have the profiler and yet we are receiving these events. Could it be something else? The reason it is bothering us is that it hides the real messages we emit through our plugins. the only way is to have a bulk deletion job, but it makes no sense to have something emitting 2K+ messages in 4h and then delete them